# Python: Register hooks to existing code to get control when a function is called

Tags: debugging, logging, inspection

I'd like to get control (to execute some pre-emptive tasks) when a function is called in Python **without modifying the source program**, e.g., when calling test()

```py
def test(i : int, s: str) -> int:
    pass
```

I'd like a function myobserver to be called, and have some way to inspect (maybe even modify?!) the parameters?  Think of it sorta like a mini-debugger, e.g., to add logging to an existing program that can't/shouldn't be modified?

```py
def myobserver(handle)
    name = get_name(handle)
    for n, arg in enumerate(get_arg_iterator(handle)):
        print("Argument {n} of function {name}: {arg}")
```

ETA: I am not looking for the traditional `decorator`, because adding a decorator requires *changing the source code*.  (In this sense, decorators are nicer than adding a print, but still similar because they require changes to source.)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your are looking for python decorators</s>:

```py
from functools import wraps
def debugger(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
        print('"'+func.__name__+'({},{})"'.format(*args, **kwargs)+" was invoked")
        # -------------------
        # Your logic here
        # -------------------
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return with_logging

@debugger
def test(i : int, s: str) -> int:
    print('We are in test', i, s)

test(10, 'hello')
```

---

**EDIT**

Since the decorator method mentioned above interferes with the source code (have to apply the `@` decorators), I propose the following:

```py
# This is source code to observe, should not be _touched_!
class SourceCode:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def test1(self, i, s):
        print('For object labeled {}, we are in {} with param {}, {}'.format(self.label, 'test1', i, s))

    def test2(self, k):
        print('For object labeled {}, we are in {} with param {}'.format(self.label, 'test2', k))
```

What I propose is perform some manual effort in writing the hooks, I am not sure if this is feasible (just occured to me, hence adding):

```py
from functools import wraps

# the following is pretty much syntactic and generic
def hook(exist_func, debugger):
    @wraps(exist_func)
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        return debugger(exist_func, *args, **kwargs)
    return run

# here goes your debugger
def myobserver(orig_func, *args, **kwargs):
    # -----------------------
    # Your logic goes here
    # -----------------------
    print('Inside my debugger')
    return orig_func(*args, **kwargs)


# ---------------------------------
obj = SourceCode('Test')

# making the wrapper ready to receive
no_iterference_hook1 = hook(obj.test1, myobserver)
no_iterference_hook2 = hook(obj.test2, myobserver)

# call your debugger on the function of your choice
no_iterference_hook1(10, 'hello')
no_iterference_hook2('Another')
```

Comment: Decorators are a (generally good) way to rewrite functions, but a decorator violates the requirement "add logging to an existing program that can't/shouldn't be modified".

Comment: @MikeG does the edited (proposed) solution help your case?

Comment: I think playing around with the second solution might free you from the need to manually register the hooks and calling them; I will update if I can figure it out!

Comment: Hooks don't solve my problem, I'm looking for something that works without code mods. :(

Comment: Without hooks, the only other option would be to add watcher to the python interpretor itself, I guess! Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229745/14739759) if it makes sense. Or use [`sys.settrace`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/hacking-together-a-simple-graphical-python-debugger-efe7e6b1f9a8/)